# AWS ListObjectsV2 runs indefinitely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I am using AWS [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjectsV2) to iterate over S3 keys. There are more than 1,000 keys, so the [output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#ListObjectsV2Output) returns me `IsTruncated=true` as it should. However the `ContinuationToken` is empty which makes the loop in my code to run indefinitely.

In case of `IsTruncated=true` the `ContinuationToken` should never be Null/Empty.

Am I missing something or is it a bug on the AWS API?

Comment: You should add the tag of the client library you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking at [`NextContinuationToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html):

> `NextContinuationToken` is sent when `isTruncated` is true, which means there are more keys in the bucket that can be listed. The next list requests to Amazon S3 can be continued with this `NextContinuationToken`. `NextContinuationToken` is obfuscated and is not a real key

`ContinuationToken` is a copy of what you sent along with the request. If you didn't send a continuation token, it won't get returned either.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: @Gilo: if it helped, please mark the answer as accepted, so that others visitors would know it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your particular issue, but this might help. Many AWS clients in the SDKs contain a paginator to help with paging operations. Have you tried using ListObjectsV2Paginator? [This is an example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/example/service/s3/listObjects/listObjects.go) of how it can be used in Go.

```
// Create the Paginator for the ListObjectsV2 operation.
p := s3.NewListObjectsV2Paginator(client, params, func(o *s3.ListObjectsV2PaginatorOptions) {
    if v := int32(maxKeys); v != 0 {
        o.Limit = v
    }
})

// Iterate through the S3 object pages, printing each object returned.
var i int
log.Println("Objects:")
for p.HasMorePages() {
    i++

    // Next Page takes a new context for each page retrieval. This is where
    // you could add timeouts or deadlines.
    page, err := p.NextPage(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to get page %v, %v", i, err)
    }

    // Log the objects found
    for _, obj := range page.Contents {
        fmt.Println("Object:", *obj.Key)
    }
}
```